# Find reference in difference scene unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm confused about finding reference `GameObject` but different Scene and set the onclick when difference scene, so I have GameManager who manage all but available only on the Main menu. So I decide to make `Dontdestroyonload`, the issue start at this, so when I play to the `MainGame` Scene, the field of GameManager at inspector will find, but I can't drag n drop different scene, right? That confuses me.

And if the GameManager at the `MainMenu` scene, the question is how to drag n drop at the `onClick` event, like I want pause button active or something else in the game.

[image: This What i Mean #1]

[image: When i play[![][2]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WddE1.png)

I tried with `onLloadscene(scene s, Mode mode)`, but nothing happens, and here the scrip for the GameManager. :

```
public static GameManager gameManager;

[Header("Main Menu panels")]
public GameObject startPanel;
public GameObject settingPanel;
public GameObject levelPanel;

[Header("InGame Panels")]
#region Panel
public GameObject pausePanel;
public GameObject ObjectivePanel;
public GameObject shopPanel;

private int click = 0;

[Header("Int Tweaks")]
public int indexLevel;
public int onlevel;

public bool isPaused;
_levelSelect LevelSelect;
public static GameManager Instance { set; get; }
public int levelindexPlayerPrefs;

private void Awake()
{
    if (gameManager != null)
    {
        Instance = this;
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
}

void Start()
{
    LevelSelect = FindObjectOfType<_levelSelect>();
    OnStart();
    onlevel = int.Parse(LevelSelect.levelIndex) + 1;
    indexLevel = int.Parse(LevelSelect.levelIndex);
    getPlayerData();
}


// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    ExitApp();
}

public void OnStart()
{
    startPanel.SetActive(true);
    settingPanel.SetActive(false);
    levelPanel.SetActive(false);
}

#region Buttons

public void startbutton()
{
    levelPanel.SetActive(true);
    startPanel.SetActive(false);
    settingPanel.SetActive(false);
}

public void backButtonMainMenu()
{
    levelPanel.SetActive(false);
    startPanel.SetActive(true);
    settingPanel.SetActive(false);
}

public void settingbutton()
{
    levelPanel.SetActive(false);
    startPanel.SetActive(false);
    settingPanel.SetActive(true);
}

public void PauseButton()
{
    Time.timeScale = 0f;
    pausePanel.SetActive(true);
    ObjectivePanel.SetActive(false);
}

public void Resume()
{
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
}

#endregion

public void ExitApp()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        click++;
        StartCoroutine(ClickTime());
        if (click>1)
        {
            print("Exit Game");
            Application.Quit();
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator ClickTime()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    click = 0;
}

public void getPlayerData()
{
    levelindexPlayerPrefs = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LevelIndex", 0);
}

public void updateLevel(int Index)
{
    if (levelindexPlayerPrefs < Index)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LevelIndex", Index);
        levelindexPlayerPrefs = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LevelIndex");
    }
}

#region onloadedScenePickRefferences

private void OnEnable()
{
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
}
private void OnDisable()
{
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
}

void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
{
    pausePanel = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PausePanel");
    ObjectivePanel = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ObjectivePanel");
}

#endregion

//public IEnumerator EndChapter()
//{
//    updateLevel(indexLevel + 1);
//    getPlayerData();
//}
```

Comment: Unity can't guarantee that two scenes will be loaded at the same time and so will not allow cross-scene references to be saved (ie, drag-and-drop in editor). You will need to manage object discovery (`FindObjectOfType`, etc) at run-time like you are already doing in `OnSceneLoaded`

Comment: @Immersive yeah but nothing happened and for the `onclick`that can't be referenced

Comment: @Syarifabdurrahman you can add callbacks to `onClick` on runtime as well via [`AddListener`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.AddListener.html) e.g. like `someButton.onClick.AddListener(()=>{ DoSomething(); });` (they won't appear in the Inspector though!). However, is this script in the main scene or is it in the scene that gets loaded later? Issue might be that `sceneLoaded` is called **before** you have added the callback to it

Comment: @derHugo well first in the main menu,  of course, when I go to MainGame scene this script also on that scene that's why i use don't destroy onload, because I think this will good if I use just 1 `GameManager`

Comment: Actually in `Awake` why do you do `Instance = this; Destroy(gameObject);`?? This immeditely destroyes the reference `Instance` you just assigned so it will always be `null`. This will also immediately cause `OnDisable` to get called so `OnSceneLoaded` is probably never executed at all? Or well ... actually `gameManager` is never set as far as I can see so .. something is definitely wrong here ;) You should end up with multiple instances of this class and the one in the latest loaded scene might always stay uninitialized as said since I guess `OnEnable` is called *too late* try `Awake` instead

Comment: The way i use it, is to have a reference to a class in one scene, that has static members, and also in the second scene, that way they can share data and references.

Comment: @GlennvanAcker you don't need these in a scene ... as soon as something is `static` it belongs to the type itslef and isn't bound to any instance at all. You can as well simply use a `public static class GlobalReferences` and store all shared references there. This way you can even have a `MonoBehaviour` within each scene set these references and only **after** it is done invoke an event to tell other scenes that the references are set by now

Comment: @derHugo I know, that's why i would propose to use shared libraries across scenes. I usually have services and modules in place to deal with that, to avoid duplicating code anyway, this way, i can keep my monobehaviour scripts small. it's common coding practice anyway, why not use it in unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would probably do:

Have a `static` class for storing and sharing all your references. It doesn't have to be in any scene but simply "lives" in the assets:

```
public static class GlobalReferences
{
    // as example just for one reference but you can implement the rest equally yourself

    // here this class actually stores the reference
    private static GameObject startPanel;

    // A public property in order to add some logic
    // other classes will always access and set the value through this property
    public static GameObject StartPanel
    {
        get
        {
            // if the reference exists return it right away
            if(startPanel) return startPanel;

            // as a fallback try to find it 
            startPanel = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("StartPanel");

            // ofcourse it might still fail when you simply try to access it 
            // in a moment it doesn't exist yet
            return startPanel;
        }

        set
        {
            startPanel = value;

            // invoke an event to tell all listeners that the startPanel
            // was just assigned
            OnStartPanelReady?.Invoke();
        }
    }

    // An event you will invoke after assigning a value making sure that
    // other scripts only access this value after it has been set
    // you can even directly pass the reference in
    public static event Action<GameObject> OnStartPanelReady;
}
```

So now in your component(s) that is(are) **in the new loaded scene** you assign the value as early as possible (`Awake)`. Here you can already store it via the Inspector since it is a scene reference:

```
public class ExampleSetter : MonoBehaviour
{
    // already reference it via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private GameObject startPanel;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // as a fallback
        if(!startPanel) startPanel = GameObject.FindObjectWithTag("startPanel");

        // assign it to the global class
        GlobalReferences.StartPanel = startPanel;
    }
}
```

And in other scenes that where already loaded before you add a listener so they do their stuff as soon as the other scene is ready:

```
public class ExampleConsumer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Debug")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject startPanel;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // Try to get the reference
        startPanel = GlobalReferences.StartPanel;

        // if this failed then wait until it is ready
        if(!startPanel)
        {
            // it is save to remove callbacks even if not added yet
            // makes sure a listener is always only added once
            GlobalReferences.OnStartPanelReady -= OnStartPanelReady;
            GlobalReferences.OnStartPanelReady += OnStartPanelReady;
        }
        // otherwise already do what you want
        else
        {
            OnStartPanelReady(startPanel);
        }
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        // always make sure to clean up callbacks when not needed anymore!
        GlobalReferences.OnStartPanelReady -= OnStartPanelReady;
    }

    private void OnStartPanelReady(GameObject newStartPanel)
    {
        startPanel = newStartPanel;
        // always make sure to clean up callbacks when not needed anymore!
        GlobalReferences.OnStartPanelReady -= OnStartPanelReady;

        // NOTE: It is possible that at this point it is null anyway if another
        // class has set this actively to null ;)

        if(startPanel)
        {
            // Now do something with the startPanel
        }
    }
}
```

The other way round when you need a reference in the new loaded Scene form the main scene ... it should already be set since the mainscene was loaded first and has already assigned its according references.

---

Now you can either go for this `static` class or simply implement the same logic for each reference that needs to be shared directly in an according component where you reference them via `drag&drop` .. it makes no difference since anyway you will use static fields and events that are not bound to any instance but the type(s) itself.